# Is this poset a lattice (Where are is the refinement of the partitions of S)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, lattice-orders, set-partition

Let $S$ be a set of all partitions defined on a nonempty set $A$. The reation $R$ on a set $S$ is defined to be $\langle\pi_1, \pi_2\rangle \in R$ iff $\pi_1$ refines $\pi_2$.

(a) show that $R$ is a partialreally struggel ordering.

This I had no problems with and simply showed that R is antisymmetric, transitive, and reflexive.

(b) Is the poset $\langle S,R\rangle$ a lattice?

I am really struggling with this one. I know a lattice means that every pair in S has a least upper bound (lub) and a greatest lower bound (glb). I can't really think of a counter example because I cannot stop thinking of $\langle \pi_1, \pi_2\rangle$ in abstract terms.

Am I right to assume that $\langle S,R\rangle = { \pi_1 \leq \pi_2 \leq \pi_3 .... \leq \pi_n} $

Now every pair in S, am I referring to $\langle \pi_n, \pi_m\rangle$ for any $n$, $m$?

I guess I need to come up with a counter example here, since my set is not really defined but in abstract terms. I don't quite see how and why?

I think I haven't fully understood what a lub, and glb (join and meet) are in the sense of a lattice. When I look at examples I cannot understand it and I think I am taking it too literally. Could someone provide me with a detailed example showing lub and glb for  a certain set as a lub, and glb and  explain why?

I would appreciate any help and corrections in the error of my thinking!!

Comment: No, you are not right to assume that $\langle S,R\rangle=\pi_1\le\pi_2\le\pi_3\le\dots\le\pi_n.$

Comment: What you have to do is show that any two partitions of a set $S$ have a glb and a lub.

Comment: For instance, given any two partitions of $S,$ call them $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2,$ define $\pi_1\wedge\pi_2=\{X\cap Y:X\in\pi_1,Y\in\pi_2\}.$ To show that $\pi_1\wedge\pi_2$ is the greatest lower bound of $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ you have to show that: **(1)** $\pi_1\wedge\pi_2$ is a partition of $S;$ **(2)** $\pi_1\wedge\pi_2\le\pi_1;$ **(3)** $\pi_1\wedge\pi_2\le\pi_2;$ **(4)** if $\pi$ is any partition of $S$ such that $\pi\le\pi_1$ and $\pi\le\pi_2,$ then $\pi\le\pi_1\wedge\pi_2.$